# Which IDS form works on the PTO website?

Tags: uspto, ids

I can't get the PTO's web system to accept my IDS. The error statement says,

> The version of the USPTO Fillable Form you are attempting to attach is
> outdated. Please go the following website to access the newest forms
> available *http://www.uspto.gov/ebc/portal/forms.htm*. Use the
> export/import feature in Adobe Reader to quickly transfer data from
> one form to another.

So I went there and got the "latest" version, which was the same version I'd submitted -- *Approved for use through 07/31/2012* -- and I downloaded Adobe in case that was the problem, but no go. I still got the same message.

So I assume this can't be the latest IDS form. Anyone know of a later one?

Comment: The EBC help desk is very helpful at 866-217-9197. The form you are using is for things filed before the AIA law was in effect. Try here https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/forms/forms-patent-applications-filed-or-after-september-16-2012

Comment: Thanks. That was the site where I got the IDS, though, and it worked out the same way. Eventually I punted. The USPTO says old forms can be used that aren't interactive, so I uploaded the IDS PDF as images. That got me a warning, but not a fatal one.

Comment: No - same site, not the same part of that site. See answer.

Comment: Not only is the EFS-Web unforgiving so is the whole process of applying and prosecuting a patent application both in the formal and substantive aspects.

Answer (score 1):

The one labeled  *Approved for use through 07/31/2012* is wrong. That was pre- AIA. Yes, they are both on the same site - but in different places on the site.

[image: screen shot forms post AIA]

You want the version of the form [here](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/forms/forms-patent-applications-filed-or-after-september-16-2012) NOT the version [here](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/forms/forms).

With the proper version the data is machine-imported into the USPTO database. With the image version someone needs to type it in and mistakes can happen.

Comment: I'd tried that one too -- the one that says, "This EFS-Web version of the SB/08 is the RECOMMENDED version," but it wouldn't open in Adobe or Foxit, so I finally gave up. As for the PTO typing it in, I imagine they have pretty decent OCR, and anyway it can't be worse than the old days of paper submissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've experienced with Foxit Phantom PDF. I believe if you make the entries in Adobe it will work. I don't know about other PDF editors.

-ZT

Comment: Useful answer however a couple of things. Usually it is best if you could expand the answer a bit, like perhaps specifying the version of Adobe Acrobat that works. Also, don't add a signature line as your name is already provided by the SE software.